# Azure Node Js Api - Create Network Interface

Tags: node.js, api, azure, sdk, network-interface

I'm trying to create a network interface in Azure, with its Node js SDK.

Though it's not working and i'm keep getting "cannot parse request". Microsofts docs aren't that helpful.

The request is:

```
{
  "resourceGroupName": "name",
  "networkInterfaceName": "another-name",
  "properties": {
    "location": "eastus2",
        "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "privateIpAddress": "10.1.10.1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The response is:

```
{
  "request": {
    "id": "7384079f-83a6-459f-b8a9-096f76db97ff",
    "url": "/network/networkInterface/",
    "method": "POST",
    "timestamp": "2017-04-19T07:40:56.022Z"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Bad Request"
    },
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": "Error",
        "message": "Cannot parse the request."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Without ipConfigurations array, I receive a response which states I must attach ipConfigurations.

Thanks,
Gilad

Comment: Could you share your code for creating a network interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've just succeeded to solve the issue.
I added a subnet properties and it worked.